# OMNeT++, <!> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.dll': The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: console, ide, omnet++, veins

I am very new to OMNeT++ and probably I miss something basic.

I use OMNeT++ IDE. When I run `omnetpp.ini` as `OMNeT++ Simulation` I get the error
`<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.dll': The specified procedure could not be found`
which is self explanatory. My problem is that the file `libveins.dll` is indeed located in `src` folder and I do not understand why it cannot be found (see picture below)

[image]

I was browsing in the files trying to track where the error is coming from, but I did not find the place where `libveins.dll` would be loaded.

Does anybody know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this error might be due to more than one factor so you should provide more information.
I had something similar while using incompatible versions of Omnetpp and Veins. Maybe you'd want to share your host system and the versions you're using. For me was enough to test different versions of the program and the frameworks. Also import/reference one framework at a time, so you know if it's a compatibility fault. E.g. I could not use veins and inet at same time for some reason.

Another hint: From your screenshot I see a red cross on the "subprojects" folder so maybe you set that as a NED source file directory? Make sure these boxes are selected.

[NED Files directory setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkCR9.png)

I'd suggest to follow this video for veins_inet cooperation: https://youtu.be/mGvhbrw05sQ?list=PLaBPUIXZ8s4AwAk5EelikvvyG4EzX2hpx

Comment: I had to reinstall OMNeT++ to make it compatible with Veins. Now I have the following verions: opmnetpp-5.6.2 and veins-5.1 and I run them on Windows 10. 

I have also followed the video you suggested, and I get the same error as in the description at the timestamp 8:16. 

Maybe I have this problem because I installed SUDO, Veins and OMNeT into directory `C:\Users\User\source` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)`?

Comment: I verify compatibility of Veins and OMNeT here https://veins.car2x.org/download/#compatibility.

Comment: In OMNeT++ 6 we made some changes to force Windows to give meaningful error messages. (i.e. what name is missing from what DLL). If you start an app from a console, Windows eats these error messages. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode for details. I.e. SetErrorMode(0) is called. Sadly, this is not present in omnet 5.x

Comment: @Eugene was right, there was some incompatibility between veins and some other program. Downloading veins from this repository https://github.com/sommer/veins solved the issue

Comment: @Python I'm happy to read that. The fact is that it works and nobody knows why. It didn't work and nobody knows why.
So on my Windows 10 it only worked Omnet562 and Veins downloaded from the website and not directly on GitHub, where usually you end up downloading to the very last commit, which might have some bugs. Same versions gave me trouble on Ubuntu, where I have Omnet6_13 and Veins master branch at pre13. I'm not happy with that but it works! Thanks for the feedback.